# How to convert a recursive excel formula to DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to transfer this excel operation to DAX in PowerBI. An illustration of the problem is shown in Excel screenshot. I am basically calculating the weighted average and placing it in the cell below. I know this same logic cannot be used in DAX. Is there a way to work around it? It is referencing the same column I am defining. I know this is possible in excel and was hoping there could be a workaround in Power BI. In my Power BI works, the columns being referenced are filtered from calculated **measures**. In the excel sheet, the columns A,B,C, and D are calculated. Here is a link to a [.pbix](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-8sjOHUXjz55UwBnIgYWFneAVXs3YBvy?usp=sharing) file of this problem. Also included is an excel solution. The screenshot of the excel solution is shown below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cut the data table by the max date and add your calculatins. The maxDate-1 you will get from Matrix visual for each row in matrix. Then add caclulated values to each row. Then filnal culculation. The idea can loks like this (I did't check):

```
VAR Y36Value=
        CALCULATE(
            SELECTEDVALUE(table[Y])
            ,LASTDATE(table[DATE])
        )

VAR filteredTable =
        FILTER(
            All(table)
           , table[starting inv]<MAX(table[starting inv])-1 && Y36Value <> 0
        )

VAR fltdTblWithValues = 
        ADDCLUMNS(
            filteredTable 
            ,"SumProductEF", [E]*[F]
            ,"SumProductYZ", [Y]*[Z]
        )
VAR result =
       DIVIDE(
           SUMX(fltdTblWithValues,([SumProductEF]-[SumProductYZ])
           ,SUMX(fltdTblWithValues,E-Y)
       )
```

If you add your values in a table format then I can check the measure.

Comment: can you take a look at the question? I added a .pbix file.

Comment: Hi, I'lllook trough tomorrow

Comment: Hi again, it's not possible to repiat excel with DAX. It's possible to reach the result with a math formula. I'll try to find a solution tomorrow.